# Referencing Question

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib

I made the BibTeX file for the references, what I want is; as a result to have in the text the author name and the year and list it in the bibliography
I write it in this way

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum,setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.0}}  %% this affects both figure and table
\setstretch{1.0}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[left=6cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setstretch{1.5}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\newcommand\seqwlimits[3]{\{#1\}_{\mathstrut#2}^{\mathstrut#3}}
\begin{document}
bla bla .... \cite{BOLLERSLEV1986307} 


\bibliography{refrences}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

My BiB file I wrote it like this:

```
@article{NIETO2016475,
title = "Frontiers in VaR forecasting and backtesting",
journal = "International Journal of Forecasting",
volume = "32",
number = "2",
pages = "475 - 501",
year = "2016",
issn = "0169-2070",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.08.003",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016920701500120X",
author = "Maria Rosa Nieto and Esther Ruiz"
}

@article{article,
    author = {Haas, Markus},
    year = {2006},
    month = {01},
    pages = {},
    title = {Improved Duration-Based Backtesting of Value-at-Risk},
    volume = {8},
    booktitle = {Journal of Risk}
}


@article{PRITSKER2006561,
    title = "The hidden dangers of historical simulation",
    journal = "Journal of Banking & Finance",
    volume = "30",
    number = "2",
    pages = "561 - 582",
    year = "2006",
    note = "Risk Management and Optimization in Finance",
    issn = "0378-4266",
    doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jbankfin.2005.04.013",
    url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037842660500083X",
    author = "Matthew Pritsker",
}

@ARTICLE{perigon,
    title = {The level and quality of Value-at-Risk disclosure by commercial banks},
    author = {Pérignon, Christophe and Smith, Daniel},
    year = {2010},
    journal = {Journal of Banking & Finance},
    volume = {34},
    number = {2},
    pages = {362-377},}

@book{jorion2001value,
    title={Value at Risk: The New Benchmark for Managing Financial Risk},
    author={Jorion, P.},
    isbn={9780071355025},
    lccn={00033239},
    series={MacGraw-Hill international editions: Finance series},
    url={https://books.google.de/books?id=S2SsFblvUdMC},
    year={2001},
    publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}

@article{BOLLERSLEV1986307,
    title = "Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity",
    journal = "Journal of Econometrics",
    volume = "31",
    number = "3",
    pages = "307 - 327",
    year = "1986",
    issn = "0304-4076",
    doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(86)90063-1",
    url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407686900631",
    author = "Tim Bollerslev"
}


@article{Riskmetrics,
    title = " RISKMETRICS. Risk management: a practical guide. 1st Edition. NewYork: RMG,
    year = "1999",}

@mastersthesis{Nieppola,
    title={Backtesting Value-at-Risk Models},
    author={Nieppola, Olli},
    year={2009},
    language={en},
    pages={78},
    type={G2 Pro gradu, diplomityö},
    url={http://urn.fi/URN:NBN:fi:aalto-201111151093},
}


@article{haas2001new,
    title={New methods in backtesting},
    author={Haas, Marcus},
    year={2001}
}

@article{campbell2005review,
    title={A review of backtesting and backtesting procedures},
    author={Campbell, Sean D and others},
    year={2005},
    publisher={Divisions of Research \& Statistics and Monetary Affairs, Federal Reserve Board}
}


@article{christoffersen2004backtesting,
    title={Backtesting value-at-risk: A duration-based approach},
    author={Christoffersen, Peter and Pelletier, Denis},
    journal={Journal of Financial Econometrics},
    volume={2},
    number={1},
    pages={84--108},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Oxford University Press}
}


@article{christoffersen1998evaluating,
    title={Evaluating interval forecasts},
    author={Christoffersen, Peter F},
    journal={International economic review},
    pages={841--862},
    year={1998},
    publisher={JSTOR}
}


@article{pajhede2017backtesting,
    title={Backtesting Value-at-Risk: A Generalized Markov Test},
    author={Pajhede, Thor},
    journal={Journal of Forecasting},
    volume={36},
    number={5},
    pages={597--613},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}


@article{berkowitz2011evaluating,
    title={Evaluating value-at-risk models with desk-level data},
    author={Berkowitz, Jeremy and Christoffersen, Peter and Pelletier, Denis},
    journal={Management Science},
    volume={57},
    number={12},
    pages={2213--2227},
    year={2011},
    publisher={INFORMS}
}

@article{ziggel2014new,
    title={A new set of improved Value-at-Risk backtests},
    author={Ziggel, Daniel and Berens, Tobias and Wei{\ss}, Gregor NF and Wied, Dominik},
    journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume={48},
    pages={29--41},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}




@article{santos2012,
    title={A new class of independence tests for interval forecasts evaluation},
    author={Santos, P Ara{\'u}jo and Alves, MI Fraga},
    journal={Computational Statistics \& Data Analysis},
    volume={56},
    number={11},
    pages={3366--3380},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I got many errors and not all entrys has been listed.

Answer (score 2):

To get all entrys cited you have in your bib file you can simply use command `\nocite{*}`.

You did not tell us which errors you got, but in your bib file are 3 errors in the following entrys:

```
@article{PRITSKER2006561,
    title = "The hidden dangers of historical simulation",
    journal = "Journal of Banking \& Finance",   <==========================

@ARTICLE{perigon,
    title = {The level and quality of Value-at-Risk disclosure by commercial banks},
    author = {Pérignon, Christophe and Smith, Daniel},
    year = {2010},
    journal = {Journal of Banking \& Finance},  <==========================

@article{Riskmetrics,
    title = "RISKMETRICS. Risk management: a practical guide. 1st Edition. NewYork: RMG",  <==========================
    year = "1999",}
```

In the first two entrys you have to mask `&` with `\`: `\&`. In the third entry is a closing `"` missing. Correct this entry completly!

So with the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to get an compilable MWE)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{NIETO2016475,
title = "Frontiers in VaR forecasting and backtesting",
journal = "International Journal of Forecasting",
volume = "32",
number = "2",
pages = "475 - 501",
year = "2016",
issn = "0169-2070",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.08.003",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016920701500120X",
author = "Maria Rosa Nieto and Esther Ruiz"
}

@article{article,
    author = {Haas, Markus},
    year = {2006},
    month = {01},
    pages = {},
    title = {Improved Duration-Based Backtesting of Value-at-Risk},
    volume = {8},
    booktitle = {Journal of Risk}
}

@article{PRITSKER2006561,
    title = "The hidden dangers of historical simulation",
    journal = "Journal of Banking \& Finance",
    volume = "30",
    number = "2",
    pages = "561 - 582",
    year = "2006",
    note = "Risk Management and Optimization in Finance",
    issn = "0378-4266",
    doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jbankfin.2005.04.013",
    url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037842660500083X",
    author = "Matthew Pritsker",
}

@ARTICLE{perigon,
    title = {The level and quality of Value-at-Risk disclosure by commercial banks},
    author = {Pérignon, Christophe and Smith, Daniel},
    year = {2010},
    journal = {Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume = {34},
    number = {2},
    pages = {362-377},}

@book{jorion2001value,
    title={Value at Risk: The New Benchmark for Managing Financial Risk},
    author={Jorion, P.},
    isbn={9780071355025},
    lccn={00033239},
    series={MacGraw-Hill international editions: Finance series},
    url={https://books.google.de/books?id=S2SsFblvUdMC},
    year={2001},
    publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}

@article{BOLLERSLEV1986307,
    title = "Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity",
    journal = "Journal of Econometrics",
    volume = "31",
    number = "3",
    pages = "307 - 327",
    year = "1986",
    issn = "0304-4076",
    doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(86)90063-1",
    url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407686900631",
    author = "Tim Bollerslev"
}

@article{Riskmetrics,
    title = " RISKMETRICS. Risk management: a practical guide. 1st Edition. NewYork: RMG",
    year = "1999",}

@mastersthesis{Nieppola,
    title={Backtesting Value-at-Risk Models},
    author={Nieppola, Olli},
    year={2009},
    language={en},
    pages={78},
    type={G2 Pro gradu, diplomityö},
    url={http://urn.fi/URN:NBN:fi:aalto-201111151093},
}

@article{haas2001new,
    title={New methods in backtesting},
    author={Haas, Marcus},
    year={2001}
}

@article{campbell2005review,
    title={A review of backtesting and backtesting procedures},
    author={Campbell, Sean D and others},
    year={2005},
    publisher={Divisions of Research \& Statistics and Monetary Affairs, Federal Reserve Board}
}

@article{christoffersen2004backtesting,
    title={Backtesting value-at-risk: A duration-based approach},
    author={Christoffersen, Peter and Pelletier, Denis},
    journal={Journal of Financial Econometrics},
    volume={2},
    number={1},
    pages={84--108},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@article{christoffersen1998evaluating,
    title={Evaluating interval forecasts},
    author={Christoffersen, Peter F},
    journal={International economic review},
    pages={841--862},
    year={1998},
    publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{pajhede2017backtesting,
    title={Backtesting Value-at-Risk: A Generalized Markov Test},
    author={Pajhede, Thor},
    journal={Journal of Forecasting},
    volume={36},
    number={5},
    pages={597--613},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{berkowitz2011evaluating,
    title={Evaluating value-at-risk models with desk-level data},
    author={Berkowitz, Jeremy and Christoffersen, Peter and Pelletier, Denis},
    journal={Management Science},
    volume={57},
    number={12},
    pages={2213--2227},
    year={2011},
    publisher={INFORMS}
}

@article{ziggel2014new,
    title={A new set of improved Value-at-Risk backtests},
    author={Ziggel, Daniel and Berens, Tobias and Wei{\ss}, Gregor NF and Wied, Dominik},
    journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume={48},
    pages={29--41},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{santos2012,
    title={A new class of independence tests for interval forecasts evaluation},
    author={Santos, P Ara{\'u}jo and Alves, MI Fraga},
    journal={Computational Statistics \& Data Analysis},
    volume={56},
    number={11},
    pages={3366--3380},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{BOLLERSLEV1986307} or \citet{BOLLERSLEV1986307}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % plain 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]

As you will see there a seven warning because there are details for several entrys missing, for example journals or authors.  Entry `Riskmetrics` needs to be completly reworked ...

If you have other errors in your TeX code I omitted please add the exact error messages to your question!